# Header and margins

Tags: header-footer, margins

1. I would like to set a thicker header line
2. I want to have a larger margin from the top and the bottom of the page.
3. I have a problem with the header, which takes the name of my section which is two sentences long - it doesn't look good. How can I avoid that without changing the section title?

I don't know if this is all you need to answer my questions:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish, english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeheadrule{headings}{\textwidth}{0.3pt}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{3mm}}

% Enable subfigures
\newsubfloat{figure}

% Path to graphics
\graphicspath{{gfx/}}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

% Avoid a warning
\pdfminorversion=5

% Define layout dimensions

\setlrmarginsandblock{35mm}{25mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{30mm}{30mm}{*}
\setheadfoot{8mm}{10mm}
\checkandfixthelayout
\OnehalfSpacing
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example (MWE), that includes your document class and a section title of the mentioned length?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) To make it easier for us to help you your example code should be a compilable LaTeX document that actually reproduces the problem. Please see [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) how you can set up such a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: `\everymath{\displaystyle}` is a wrong thing to do. If you are upset because limits in inline sums or similar constructions are not above and below the symbol, you shouldn't be. Compare `$\sum$` and `$\displaystyle\sum$` (without that declaration, of course), and you'll understand why.

Answer (score 2):

1. Change the value used in the third argument of `\makeheadrule`; you are currently using `0.3pt` so you could use a bigger value; in the example below I used `1pt`; this value is perhaps too big, but it was used just for the example; you can choose the value that best suits your needs.
2. Increase the values used in the second and third argument for `\setulmarginsandblock`; in my example I used `\setulmarginsandblock{90mm}{90mm}{*}`
   just for illustration.
3. The sectional unit commands in memoir offer you two optional arguments to control the information in the ToC and in the headers, so you can say

   ```
   \section[Title in ToC][Title in Header]{Title in document}
   ```

   or, if only one of the optional arguments is used,

   ```
   \section[Title in ToC and Header]{Title in document}
   ```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeheadrule{headings}{\textwidth}{1pt}

\setlrmarginsandblock{35mm}{25mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{90mm}{90mm}{*}
\setheadfoot{8mm}{10mm}
\checkandfixthelayout
\OnehalfSpacing

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter}
\section[Title in ToC][Title in Header]{A section with a really long title; it is so long that it will span several lines}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

An image of one of the resulting pages:

[image]

Not related to your question, nut the rule you defined with

```
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{3mm}}
```

will produce a really thick rule; perhaps you would like to reduce the second argument of `\rule`?

Comment: Such a thick line may be good for obituaries, not for pretty documents.

Comment: @egreg hehe! Yes, thats' why I added  "this value is too big, but it was used just for the example" in my answer.

Comment: And, if 2pt is too big (and it is), 3mm is incredibly huge, because it's about 8.5pt.

Comment: @egreg in fact, I was really using `3pt`! I decided to go for `1pt` so not to offend anybody's eyes; I also made a warning about the `3mm` in `\HRule`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I still don't know how to make the title in the header smaller. Should I add: [Title in Header] next to each section title?

Comment: @Sarah what exactly do you mean with "how to make the title in the header smaller"? Do you mean you want to reduce the font size?